# How to blink LED with 1.8V?

Tags: level-shifting, intel

I am experimenting with an Intel Edison mini breakout board with pinout like here: http://fab-lab.eu/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/Edison_IO_LED.jpg

Now, I soldered header pins to plug the board into a breadboard. Unfortunately, the GPIO levels are only 1.8V.

- What should I do to make a LED blink from here (on a breadboard ideally)?
- What else can be done with 1.8V GPIO levels?

UPDATE: It works with a BC547

However, depending on the blink frequency, it seems that LED does not turn ON completely. Might it be because the base resistor is 0 ?

[image: blink_transistor]

Comment: Could you clarify what do you mean by "the LED does not turn ON completely"? Also, I don't see any resistors on your breadboard - how do you limit the current through the LED?

Comment: the problem was indeed the missing base resistor to limit the current. Without that resistor, the collector current is not full steam I guess, and the LED does sometimes not blink

Comment: It's more probable that GPIO pins have some sort of short-circuit protection which detects a short circuit and cuts the current through the pin.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1.8V is enough to drive a transistor which can be used to power all kinds of loads. Example:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fHVWmG.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: thanks, I have some BC547 https://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Components/BC546.pdf - let me check how that circuits applies

Comment: I got it working - but why would I need the base resistor?

Comment: To limit the current in your 1.8V output pin.

Comment: Also to limit the current through the base-emitter junction, which could destroy the transistor.

Comment: @Steve according to the datasheet, BC547 can handle up to 200 mA of base current (peak value), so I would be surprised to see it destroyed by the current from a GPIO pin.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev - Steve's comment was a general one, and useful to keep in mind when driving transistors from a voltage source. I agree that there aren't many microcontrollers or microprocessors that will damage your transistor, but it's a good habit to get into, so you don't get burned in the future if you happen to use another source.

Comment: If you hate the base resistor you could use a MOSFET however the ones rated for 1.8V drive are going to be SMT only so you'd need a breakout board etc. to easily prototype on your perf board.