# Driving LED with 1.8V GPIO

Tags: transistors, led, gpio

I’m currently making a board that needs to drive an external 20 mA red LED using a 1.8V GPIO pin. The LED is mounted on an separate board with a resistor as seen in the diagram. My board is supplied with 3.3V from this separate board.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ffhMEf.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Can this be done with 1 or 2 transistors? I know that I need to step up the GPIO voltage seeing as the LED has a forward voltage of around 1.8-2V, but I am unsure of how to go about it. Most examples I have been able to find have a transistor on the cathode side of the LED as opposed to this setup, e.g. this post [How to blink LED with 1.8V?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/207363/how-to-blink-led-with-1-8v)

Comment: If the LED has higher Vf than your Vcc, there will be little to no light.

Comment: The one-transistor circuit will be fine, you just need to invert (in software) the signal coming out of the MCU. (And the 3.3 V rail is shorted to ground in the diagram on the right in the question.) Is the start-up state of the LED important until the MCU has initialized?

Comment: have you tried directly running the LED from the GPIO? it should work just fine, though it won't reach it's 20ma brightness that Vf is specified at. The LED's V-vs-I curve means that you'll likely draw between 1-10ma. It's not a cliff, so if you source under but close to Vf, then there's some wiggle room to non-specifically illuminate the LED.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't have headroom between V<sub>F,max</sub> of your LED to your supply, there will be problems as one batch of boards will have (some) light (lucky low V<sub>F</sub> batch) and other none (unlucky high V<sub>F</sub> batch) despite everything working.

Since you seem to have access to 3.3 V as well, I propose to do the following:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fu4q7Q.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Your M1 MOSFET (N-FET) needs to have <1.8 V Vgth and M2 (P-FET) needs <3.3 V Vgsth.

Alternatively, if your MCU has some output current from its GPIO pins, use an NPN transistor:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fhe9LU.png)</sup>

Q1 could be just about any NPN. M2 (P-FET) needs to have <3.3 V Vgsth.

Comment: The resistor and LED are fixed on a seperate board with the cathode going to ground, and I can only connect to the resistor side (marked EXT.), like in the right side of my diagram. Could I still use a MOSFET to connect to the resistor side of the LED?

Comment: Oh, then you need to switch on the high side. Let me modify the schematic for you.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I was looking for. The GPIO doesn't have much output current, so I think the two FETs will be the best solution. How would I go about calculating the required GPIO current for that setup?

Comment: (Vcc/R3)/hfe. If you can tolerate slot turn-off, just increase R3 to very high and choose a small signal NPN with high hfe/beta. Adjust your R2 resistor to match.

Comment: It might be worthwhile to search MCU's data sheet to see if **1.8V_GPIO** is 3.3V-tolerant. If so, then a logic-level PMOS will suffice, along with a pullup resistor.